# ASP.NET MVC5 Display data in calendar

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, mongodb, calendar

I have done an application which allow people to manage holidays days in a company. And Now,
I would like to display these holidays on a Calendar.
I used ASP.NET MVC 5, and a MongoDB for this project. This is my first project using ASP.NET so I'm new with it.

I have been looking for some tutorials, but I couldn't find what I want, all tutorials are pretty old and using WebForms. I found some information about Event Calendar class but it looks pretty old aswell...
If you have any idea, tips, tutorials that I should have a look just tell me.

Thanks,

Comment: you can use simple jquery ui calender and use simple jquery for your purpose

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a Calendar with MVC consider using some javascript calendar.

I can recommend this one:

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

> FullCalendar is a jQuery plugin that provides a full-sized, drag &
>   drop calendar like the one below. It uses AJAX to fetch events
>   on-the-fly for each month and is easily configured to use your own
>   feed format (an extension is provided for Google Calendar). It is
>   visually customizable and exposes hooks for user-triggered events
>   (like clicking or dragging an event). It is open source licensed under
>   an MIT license.

Comment: This looks great, but I need to find some samples codes about it, I'm new to ASP.NET and starting from scratch seem a bit tricky

Comment: @user3848695 here you go - http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/638674/Full-calendar-A-complete-web-diary-system-for-jQue

Answer (score 2):

Using Jquery UI Calendar, you can do it easily as:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
   var SelectedDates = {};
   SelectedDates[new Date('04/05/2014')] = new Date('04/05/2014');
   SelectedDates[new Date('05/04/2014')] = new Date('05/04/2014');
   SelectedDates[new Date('06/06/2014')] = new Date('06/06/2014');

   var newDt = new Date();
   var year = newDt.getFullYear(); // Current Year

   $('#dvCalendar').datepicker({
     defaultDate: new Date((parseInt(year, 10) - 1), 12, 31),
     numberOfMonths: [4, 3],
     changeMonth: false,
     changeYear: false,
     duration: 'fast',
     stepMonths: 0,
     beforeShowDay: function(date) {
        var Highlight = SelectedDates[date];
        if (Highlight) {
            return [true, "Highlighted", Highlight];
        }
        else {
            return [true, '', ''];
        }
    }
  });
});
```

HTML

```
 <div id="dvCalendar">
 </div>
```

AND **CSS**

```
body
{
  font-family:Arial;
  font-size : 10pt;
  padding:5px;
}

.Highlighted a{
 background-color : Green !important;
 background-image :none !important;
 color: White !important;
 font-weight:bold !important;
 font-size: 12pt;
}
```

jsFiddle [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/pawankullu/odau1r41/12/) is here:

Comment: Datepicker is too small, I need a full Calendar

Comment: Ok, you can show full year calendar inside div..plz see updated ans

Comment: @user3848695, I have a working demo on jsfiddle please check ;)

Comment: Thanks you, this is really good, but the problem is with datepicker, I can't see if there is more than 1 people who have request that day.